# JavaFX ListView with 3 Columns per Row

Tags: java, android, listview, javafx, fxml

I'm just wondering if JavaFX has some kind of equivalent to Android's ListView/RecyclerView, wherein each listItem itself contains a view that can hold multiple other views.

```
 @FXML
 private ListView<String> listViewGreen;

 private void displayTickets(String[] dataArray, ListView <String> listView) {
     ObservableList <String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataArray);
     listViewPriority.setItems(observableList);
 }
```

As far as I know, I'm restricted to passing a String array into the ObservableList, allowing my list to hold a single value per row. I would like each row to have three columns, i.e. a Ticket Number, Summary, and Due Date. How can this be achieved... other than simply concatenating each of these values and feeding them into the original String array.

Comment: A `ListView` with multiple columns is surely a `TableView`. In general, you can create a `ListView` for any data type (not just `String`). For example, you can define a `Ticket` class, and make a `ListView<Ticket>` (or `TableView<Ticket>`). You can display the cells (for either lists or tables) any way you want by setting the cell factory on the list view (or on the columns in a table view). Your question really boils down to "How do I use `ListView`s and `TableView`s", which is way too broad for this forum: have a look at some tutorials and post specific questions if/when they occur.

Comment: Lots of people seem to like [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) on table views, and of course the standard [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/ui_controls.htm#JFXUI336) has sections on both `ListView` and `TableView`.

Comment: This might be useful if you want spreadsheet like editing where losing focus (or hitting enter/tab key) on one field commits the data and moves to the next. There are known issues with exactly this scenario in TableViews (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089514) which are still open after 8 years!